# Не сохраняется токен в LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, fetch

Есть файл `Token` с запросом

```
export default async function Token(email, password) {
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Could not fetch');
  }
  return fetch(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
}
```

От него создается отдельный файл с запросом на сохранение токена в LocalStorage.

```
import Token from '../requests';
import saveToken from '../token';

export default function login(email, password) {
  return Token(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then(saveToken)
    .catch(() => {
      alert('failed');
    });
}
```

Сам файл `token`

```
export default function saveToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
}
```

На данном этапе после заполнения формы в localstorage токен полностью отсутствует (Туда вообще ничего не прилетает). Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: ошибки? лог сообщение выводится из `saveToken()`?

Comment: нет, ничего не выводится

Comment: А на какой url прилетает fetch?

Comment: На тот, что в fetch указан, все туда летит

Comment: мне кажется там просто нет токена на входе. надо каждый `then` отладить на наличие входных данных. Сразу станет понятно в чем дело

Comment: сейчас, пока писал сюда, заметил еще одну вещь, что при вводе данных в случае,  если данные неверные, то выбивало ошибку 404, сейчас оно пропускает любые значения в форме, где-то ошибся в самих запросах, не подскажете, в чем дело?

Comment: Я к чему спрашиваю: у вас `Token(email, password)` принимает email и password, а вы передаете ```Token(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
      method: 'POST'
    })```

Comment: Да, не спорю, ошибки в коде есть 100% ) Я новичок в этом деле, поэтому хотел бы узнать, что подправить, чтобы работало корректно, возможно я не туда задавал ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что в Token() надо передавать login и password:

```
export default function login(email, password) {
  return Token(email, password)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    // ... и далее по коду
}
```

И из объявления функции Token() стоит убрать все, что относится к res:

```
export default async function Token(email, password) {
  return fetch(`/api/login?pass=${password}&user=${email}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
}
```

Ну и вообще почитать про [POST-запросы](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch#post-zaprosy).